# Jumi plugin URLs not replaced by Joomla SEF plugin

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, jumi

I am using Jumi to generate a short list of links on a page.

However, the links are not being converted by the Joomla system sef plugin, although any other links on the page are being correctly converted.

I have tried changing the order of the Jumi plugin and the Joomla SEF plugin by using the plugin manager, but it doesn't affect the result.

For example
in my article I have the following

```
{jumi [test.php]}
```

and in test.php I have this:

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1120&Itemid=234">Testing</a>';
```

When I view the article from the front end the url in the href of the testing link is in its non-sef form, whereas other identical urls (inserted in the editor, not by the plugin) have been correctly converted by the Joomla SEF plugin.

I am not using any other plugins or routers that might affect this (eg. I am not using SEF404 or similar, just Jumi and the standard system plugins.

Many thanks for how to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you change the order of the plugins, that won't work. The thing is, Jumi runs independently of the rest of the website, and so the data there cannot be modified by any plugin (again, regardless of the plugin order).

You should try using the JRoute function with the link.

Comment: Could you please explain more what you mean by 'jumi runs independently of the rest of the website'? As I understand it the jumi plugin is a standard plugin, and I am not using the component. Thanks for the suggestion of using the router, are you suggesting that I call `Jrouter::_()` ?